# Opening .xlsm file with Apache POI crashes Tomcat

Tags: java, excel, tomcat, jasper-reports, apache-poi

I am trying to copy data between two excel files using Apache POI (3.7).

File A contains raw data generated with JasperReports. File B has two sheets. The first sheet contains tables that get populated using a macro and the second sheet contains the data feeding the tables from the first sheet.

My mission is to get the data from the first file into the second sheet of the second file.

The code is working with every single xlsm file on the face of the earth except the one I need to get working...

The code:

```
    if (outputfile.getAbsolutePath().contains(".xlsx") ||      outputfile.getAbsolutePath().contains(".xlsm")) {
        FileInputStream inputStreamForReport = new FileInputStream(outputfile);
        pack = OPCPackage.open(inputStreamForReport);
        outputWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(pack);
        inputStreamForReport.close();
    } else {
        inputStream2 = new FileInputStream(outputfile);
        fileSystem2 = new POIFSFileSystem(inputStream2);
        outputWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileSystem2);
        inputStream2.close();
    }
```

As I mentioned earlier this works with every file except the one I need to get working. If I use that one file, when I get to this line:

```
outputWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(pack);
```

Tomcat just sits there without doing anything. Using htop I can see that one of the cores is at 100%. This goes on forever and ever, and Tomcat dies. I don't get any kind of message in the logs, it just sits there. I am using Tomcat7.

You can find the file that has been driving me insane here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4tieEreAMvUdUdHQ1doM2lzbFU/view?usp=sharing

I have no clue about how macros work. So it may be a stupid error.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Apache POI 3.7 is a little old. What happens if you try a newer version, eg 3.11 beta 3?

Comment: I will try that and tell you how it went. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Gagravarr, you saved me. I used 3.10.FINAL and it works! I didn't want to switch versions because other parts of the project are using 3.7 and I didn't want to risk breaking those parts. I'm going to test those parts to see if everything works fine. THANK YOU!